# How do I install Skype (or anything) using snap?

Tags: software-installation, skype, snap

I have downloaded Skype using snap. The only way I can access it, is via the terminal. 
When I try to launch Skype, I get the following message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/.config': Permission denied
/snap/skype/48/bin/electron-launch: 15: /snap/skype/48/bin/electron-launch: 
cannot create /.config/skypeforlinux/logs/skype-startup.log: Directory nonexistent
```

What do I do?

Comment: Your title speaks different from your question, which is it? let me install it and see for myself!

Comment: The question iis actually "how do I launch Skype?". But part of the answer is that I have not installed it properly. I installed Skype using snap. But launching Skype returned the error message shown above.

Comment: Did you run the command `sudo snap install --classic skype`?

Comment: no, just "sudo snap install skype". I tried with the "--classic", but "--classic" was not recognized.

Comment: What ubuntu version is this?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

When I search for skype snap, I see official skype from skype and skypeforlinux-test.

Make sure you installed official Skype (with --classic parameter). It creates also shortcut in menu and can be started from menu, no need for command line.

If you still have problems show us output of `snap list` and `snap info <snapname>`